# Ubuntu 14.04 volume buttons don't work properly

Tags: 14.04, sound, button

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and now the three volume buttons (increase, decrease, mute) on my laptop (Lenovo T400) don't work properly. After reboot they work fine, but after some hours (cannot really say when it starts to change, since I don't use those buttons all the time) they just don't respond anymore. I can adjust the volume manually by clicking on the volume symbol in the upper right corner, but the shortcuts seem to be disabled.

Does anyone else has this problem, or does anyone know a way to fix it?